# Calculating bounds interpolation and approximation

Tags: numerical-methods

If I have a function $f(x)=e^x$ and nodes $x_0=a-h/\sqrt(3)$ and $x_1=a+h/\sqrt(3)$ to linearly interpolate $f(x)$ on the interval $[a-h,a+h]$ for some real numbers $a$ and $h$, $h>0$.  How do I calculate the bound for $\max|f(x)-P_1(x)|$?  Also, how would I choose values for $h$ and $a$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the question asks you to choose $h$ and $a$, but asks for the error bound for general $h$ and $a$. If this is the case, we first find the interpolation polynomial $P_1(x) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x$ by

$$ exp(x_0) = f(x_0) = P_1(x_0) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_0 $$
$$ exp(x_1) = f(x_1) = P_1(x_1) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_1 $$

On solving we obtain,

$$ \alpha_0 = \frac{x_1 exp(x_0) - x_0 exp(x_1)}{x_1 - x_0} $$
$$ \alpha_1 = \frac{exp(x_1) - exp(x_0)}{x_1 - x_0} $$

We can find $f(x) - P_1(x)$ explicitly. Note that

$$f(x) - P_1(x) \geq 0 \quad \forall x \in [a-h, a+h] \setminus [x_0, x_1]$$
$$f(x) - P_1(x) \leq 0 \quad \forall x \in [x_0, x_1]$$

Then by finding roots of the first derivative, i.e. $f'(x) - P_1'(x) = 0$, we can find the local extrema of $|f(x) - P_1(x)|$ and therefore the global maximum, which is the largest among the local extrema and the end-points.